# Unhandled Exception: 'package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart'

Tags: flutter

```
  Firebase Phone authentication in flutter,  
Phone authentication code was working perfectly for flutter firebase plugins- `firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5`, `firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9`, `cloud_firestore: ^0.13.0+1

Now updated to- `firebase_auth: ^0.20.0+1`, `firebase_core: ^0.7.0`, `cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0` 

its throwing error: 
        
        >     Unhandled Exception: 'package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart': Failed assertion: line 633 pos 12: 'codeAutoRetrievalTimeout != null': is not true

 
My Code
        
//Firebase Phone auth code
              Future<bool> loginUser(String phone ,BuildContext context) async{
                 FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
              final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
              String name = prefs.getString('roleName');
              final bloc = BlocProvider.of<AppRrgisterationScreenBloc>(context);
              _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
                  // phoneNumber: phone,
                  phoneNumber: '+91${phone}',
                  timeout: Duration(seconds: 0),
                  verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential credential) async{
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
                    User user = result.user;
                    if(user != null){
                      contactnumberVal=phone;
                      validateAndCreateData(bloc,context);
                    }else{
                      print("Error");
                    }
            
//This callback would gets called when verification is done automaticlly
                  },
                  verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException exception){
                    print(exception);
                  },
                  codeSent: (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]){
                    showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        barrierDismissible: false,
                        builder: (context) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            title: Text("Please enter the verification code sent to the mobile number and select Confirm",style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                            )),
                            content:Form(
                              key: _resetKey,
                              autovalidate: _validate,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  TextFormField(
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                    controller: verificationcode,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            actions: <Widget>[
                              showErrorMessageVerificationCode ?
                              Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    
                                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80.0)
                                  ),
                                  child: Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                      child: Text('Code is Requried!',style: TextStyle(color:Color( 0xFFE9140B),fontSize: 16.0),)
                                  )
                              )
                                  : Container(),
                              SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                              FlatButton(
                                child: Text("Cancel"),
                                textColor: Colors.white,
                                color: Color(0xFFE9140B),
                                onPressed:   () => Navigator.pop(context),
                              ),
                              FlatButton(
                                child: Text("Confirm"),
                                textColor: Colors.white,
                                color: Color(0xFFE9140B),
                                onPressed: () async{
                                  
                                  final code = verificationcode.text.trim();
                                  AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: code);
            
                                   _auth.signInWithCredential();
                                  UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential).catchError((error) {
                                    print("error");
                                    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => MobileAuthFails(names:name,phone:phone,)
                                      
                                      ),
                                          ModalRoute.withName(""));
            
                                   
                                  });
            
  //Role base sign up
                                  User user = result.user;
                                  if(user != null){
                                    contactnumberVal=phone;
                                    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                                    prefs.setString('reg_number', phone);
                                    prefs.setString('phoneNumber', phone);
                                    validateAndCreateData(bloc,context);
            
                                    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) =>
                                            MyAppEligiblity(phone:phone)
                                      // ResetPassword(user: user,)
                                    ),
                                        ModalRoute.withName(""));
                                    prefs.setBool('IsLogin', true);
                                  }
                                  else{
                                    print("error");
                                  }
                                },
                              )
            
                            ],
            
                          );
                        }
                    );
                  },
            
                codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: null,
                  // codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId){
                  //   verificationId = verificationId;
                  //   print(verificationId);
                  //   print("Timout");         }
              );
              }
```

1.verificationCompleted: Automatic handling of the SMS code on Android devices.

2.verificationFailed: Handle failure events such as invalid phone numbers or whether the SMS quota has been exceeded.

3.codeSent: Handle when a code has been sent to the device from Firebase, used to prompt users to enter the code.

4.codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: Handle a timeout of when automatic SMS code handling fails.

Comment: Please share your code where the authentication is happening.

Comment: I have posted the code @PreetShah

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `codeAutoRetrievalTimeout` as null. It requires you to pass a function over there. This function is used to perform an action when the Auto code retrieval has timed out. So, if you don't have any use for this function, please put an empty function as follows:

```dart
codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {}
```

You can find sample code and other documentation over [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/phone/) it is very helpful.

Also, please ensure that you share your code and error log the next time you have any problems.

Comment: Flutter app crashed after Adding   codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {}                                                                                          
                                                                                                       
                                                                                                       
E/AndroidRuntime(17787): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(17787): Process: com.example.jeevarakta_app, PID: 17787
E/AndroidRuntime(17787): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution @PreetShah

Comment: You will need to share with me the entire error log. This much doesn't help. Add it to the Question itself and also ensure that you add the changes you made.